# spool space issue due to inequality condition

Tags: performance, teradata

I am facing a spool space issue for one of my query.Below is the query:

```
    SEL * from (

    SEL A.ICCUSNO,
    B.ACACCNO,
    D.PARTY_ID, 
    E.PARTY_IDENTIFICATION_NUM,
    E.PARTY_IDENTIFICATION_TYPE_CD,
    A.ICIDTY,
    A.ICIDNO AS ICIDNO,
    A.ICEXPD,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ICCUSNO ORDER BY ICEXPD DESC ) AS ICEFFD2
    FROM GE_SANDBX.GE_CMCUST A
    INNER JOIN GE_SANDBX.GE_CMACCT B
    ON A.ICCUSNO=B.ACCUSNO 
    INNER JOIN GE_VEW.ACCT C
    ON B.ACACCNO=C.ACCT_NUM
    AND C.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD='ILL'
    INNER JOIN GE_VEW.PARTY_ACCT_HIST D
    ON C.ACCT_ID=D.ACCT_ID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN GE_VEW.GE_PI E
    ON D.PARTY_ID=E.PARTY_ID
    AND A.ICIDTY=E.PARTY_IDENTIFICATION_TYPE_CD
    AND E.DSTC NOT IN( 'SCRM', 'BCRM')
    --WHERE B.ACACCNO='0657007129'
    --WHERE A.ICIDNO<>E.PARTY_IDENTIFICATION_NUM
    QUALIFY  ICEFFD2=1) T
    where t.PARTY_IDENTIFICATION_NUM<>t.ICIDNO;
```

I am trying to pick one record based on expiry date ICEXPD. My inner query gives me one record per customer no ICCUSNO as below:
I

```
CCUSNO ACACCNO PARTY_ID Party_Identification_Num    Party_Identification_Type_Cd    ICIDNO  ICEXPD  ICEFFD2
    100000013   500010207   5,862,640   1-0121-2073-7   S   1-0212-2073-4   9/20/2007   1
```

But i have update the table only when the PARTY_IDENTIFICATION_NUM doesn't match with the ICIDNO.

Below is the explain plan:

```
1) First, we lock GE_SANDBX.A for access, we lock
     GE_SANDBX.B for access, we lock DP_TAB.PARTY_ACCT_HIST for
     access, we lock DP_TAB.GE_PI for access, and we
     lock DP_TAB.ACCT for access.
  2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from DP_TAB.ACCT by way of
     an all-rows scan with a condition of (
     "DP_TAB.ACCT.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD = 'ILL '") into Spool 3
     (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool
     3 is estimated with no confidence to be 9,834,342 rows (
     344,201,970 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 2.18
     seconds.
  3) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of a
     RowHash match scan, which is joined to DP_TAB.PARTY_ACCT_HIST by
     way of a RowHash match scan with no residual conditions.  Spool 3
     and DP_TAB.PARTY_ACCT_HIST are joined using a merge join, with a
     join condition of ("Acct_Id = DP_TAB.PARTY_ACCT_HIST.ACCT_ID").
     The result goes into Spool 4 (all_amps), which is redistributed by
     the hash code of (DP_TAB.ACCT.Acct_Num) to all AMPs.  Then we do a
     SORT to order Spool 4 by row hash.  The size of Spool 4 is
     estimated with no confidence to be 13,915,265 rows (487,034,275
     bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.98 seconds.
  4) We execute the following steps in parallel.
       1) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from GE_SANDBX.B by way of a
          RowHash match scan with no residual conditions, which is
          joined to Spool 4 (Last Use) by way of a RowHash match scan.
          GE_SANDBX.B and Spool 4 are joined using a merge join,
          with a join condition of ("GE_SANDBX.B.ACACCNO =
          Acct_Num").  The result goes into Spool 5 (all_amps) fanned
          out into 18 hash join partitions, which is redistributed by
          the hash code of (GE_SANDBX.B.ACCUSNO) to all AMPs.  The
          size of Spool 5 is estimated with no confidence to be
          13,915,265 rows (2,657,815,615 bytes).  The estimated time
          for this step is 1.33 seconds.
       2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from GE_SANDBX.A by way
          of an all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 6
          (all_amps) fanned out into 18 hash join partitions, which is
          redistributed by the hash code of (GE_SANDBX.A.ICCUSNO)
          to all AMPs.  The size of Spool 6 is estimated with high
          confidence to be 12,169,929 rows (5,427,788,334 bytes).  The
          estimated time for this step is 52.24 seconds.
       3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from
          DP_TAB.GE_PI by way of an all-rows scan with a
          condition of (
          "(DP_TAB.GE_PI.DSTC <> 'BSCRM')
          AND (DP_TAB.GE_PI.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD <>
          'SCRM')") into Spool 7 (all_amps), which is built locally on
          the AMPs.  The size of Spool 7 is estimated with low
          confidence to be 161,829 rows (19,419,480 bytes).  The
          estimated time for this step is 1.97 seconds.
  5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 5 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 6 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 5 and Spool 6 are joined using a hash join
     of 18 partitions, with a join condition of ("ICCUSNO = ACCUSNO").
     The result goes into Spool 8 (all_amps), which is redistributed by
     the hash code of (DP_TAB.PARTY_ACCT_HIST.PARTY_ID,
     TRANSLATE((GE_SANDBX.A.ICIDTY )USING
     LATIN_TO_UNICODE)(VARCHAR(255), CHARACTER SET UNICODE, NOT
     CASESPECIFIC)) to all AMPs.  The size of Spool 8 is estimated with
     no confidence to be 15,972,616 rows (8,593,267,408 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 4.37 seconds.
  6) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 7 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 8 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 7 and Spool 8 are right outer joined using a
     single partition hash join, with condition(s) used for
     non-matching on right table ("NOT (ICIDTY IS NULL)"), with a join
     condition of ("(PARTY_ID = Party_Id) AND ((TRANSLATE((ICIDTY
     )USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE))= Party_Identification_Type_Cd)").  The
     result goes into Spool 2 (all_amps), which is built locally on the
     AMPs.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated with no confidence to be
     16,053,773 rows (10,306,522,266 bytes).  The estimated time for
     this step is 2.11 seconds.
  7) We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step from Spool 2 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan into Spool 13 (Last Use), which is
     redistributed by hash code to all AMPs.  The result rows are put
     into Spool 11 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The
     size is estimated with no confidence to be 16,053,773 rows (
     18,558,161,588 bytes).
  8) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 11 (Last Use) by way of
     an all-rows scan with a condition of ("(Party_Identification_Num
     <> ICIDNO) AND (Field_10 = 1)") into Spool 16 (group_amps), which
     is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 16 is estimated
     with no confidence to be 10,488,598 rows (10,404,689,216 bytes).
     The estimated time for this step is 2.20 seconds.
  9) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 16 are sent back to the user as the result
     of statement 1.
```

All the required stats are collected.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can anyone please advice on this ?

Comment: Try moving the ROW_NUMBER on GE_SANDBX.GE_CMCUST into a Derived Table to calculate it before the join.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth,
You mean like this:
A.ICIDNO AS ICIDNO,
    A.ICEXPD,
    ( SEL ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ICCUSNO ORDER BY ICEXPD DESC FROM GE_SANDBX.GE_CMCUST ) AS ICEFFD2
    FROM GE_SANDBX.GE_CMCUST A
    INNER JOIN GE_SANDBX.GE_CMACCT B
    ON A.ICCUSNO=B.ACCUSNO 
    INNER JOIN GE_VEW.ACCT C

I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Isn't that we should avoid using derived tables as much as possible?

Comment: No, this is a Scalar Subquery (and you really should avoid them), I ment `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER..)`